Getting "Invalid secrets ownership" error while using chainlink functions on Ethereum Sepolia
I'm trying to use chainlink functions with self-hosted secrets and the JavaScript execution failed with the following error: Invalid secrets ownership in Ethereum Sepolia.
I was following this example: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/smart-contract-examples/blob/main/functions-examples/examples/7-use-secrets-url/gen-offchain-secrets.js for generating the off-chain secrets and then this one: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/smart-contract-examples/blob/main/functions-examples/examples/7-use-secrets-url/request.js for getting the encrypted secrets Urls.
This is my code:
await secretsManager.initialize();
  const encryptedSecretsObj = await secretsManager.encryptSecrets(secrets);
  const secretsUrls = [`${chainlinkSecretsUrl}/${network}/${version}`];
  const encryptedSecretsUrls = await secretsManager.encryptSecretsUrls(
    secretsUrls
  );


cannot repro error based on this. Also, this may be because the signer of the secrets is different from the person trying to use them? Check the PRIVATE_KEY env var's value for each of those scripts?
see:  https://github.com/smartcontractkit/smart-contract-examples/blob/fa88a66fae44309ee2455440a6c893305fdff5e7/functions-examples/examples/7-use-secrets-url/gen-offchain-secrets.js#L28
